# Docker container start error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, docker

```
canerapp:
  image: tomcat
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
```

this is my compose.yml.
 when i run to up

> caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$ docker-compose up Creating
>   homework_canerapp_1 Attaching to homework_canerapp_1 canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.362 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.363 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server
>   built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   07:31:53.364 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.36.0 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.364 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.4.0-34-generic canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.364 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   07:31:53.364 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.7.0_111-b01 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.365 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.365 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.365 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.365 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed canerapp_1 
>   | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.366 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.7 using APR version 1.5.1.
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.367 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:53.422 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016) canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.256 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.282 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.285 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   2933 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.373 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.374 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:54.442
>   INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.275 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished
>   in 1,832 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.275 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.337 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has
>   finished in 61 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.337 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.372 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished
>   in 35 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.373 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.475 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has
>   finished in 103 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.475 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.949 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has
>   finished in 474 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.954 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.966 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 07:31:56.969 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2683 ms

what i want to do is, seeing an simple html file in my web local host after i run compose up. but i cant see anything in 8080 8000 8009 ports in localhost.

also when i change yml to this

```
canerapp:
  image: tomcat
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
volumes:
     - ./html:/home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html
```

it says

> In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'volumes' must be a mapping
>   not an array.

my file directory is like that

> caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$ pwd
>   /home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$
>   ls docker-compose.yml  html caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$ ls
>   html index.html caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$
>
> homework  html   indx.html  docker-compose.yml

this is also my index.html

```
welcome hello world
```

what am i doin wrong?

edit:

i changed my compose to this

```
version: '2'
services: 
 canerapp:
   image: tomcat
   ports:
     - "8090:8091"
   volumes:
     - ./html/index.html:/var/www/html
```

and now logs are

> caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$ docker-compose logs  Attaching to
>   homework_canerapp_1 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.353 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server
>   built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:04.354 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.36.0 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.4.0-34-generic canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:04.354 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.7.0_111-b01 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.354 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed canerapp_1 
>   | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.355 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.7 using APR version 1.5.1.
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.356 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.359 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016) canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.442 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.452 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.454 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   530 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.476 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.476 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.486
>   INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.927 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished
>   in 441 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.927 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.973 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has
>   finished in 46 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.973 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.996 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished
>   in 23 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:04.996 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.018 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has
>   finished in 22 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.018 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.324 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has
>   finished in 306 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.327 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.333 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:05.333 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 879 ms
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:46.959 INFO [Thread-3]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:47.015 INFO
>   [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:47.067 INFO [Thread-3]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service
>   Catalina canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:47.124 INFO [Thread-3]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:47.175 INFO
>   [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:32:47.228 INFO [Thread-3]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:32:47.230 INFO
>   [Thread-3] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.981 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version: 
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server
>   built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.982 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   8.0.36.0 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Linux canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   4.4.0-34-generic canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.982 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:
>   1.7.0_111-b01 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.982 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   /usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed canerapp_1 
>   | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.983 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016
>   08:33:15.984 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.984 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.7 using APR version 1.5.1.
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.984 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:15.987 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016) canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.078 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.093 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.096 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   543 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.126 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service Catalina canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.126 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.141
>   INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.619 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished
>   in 477 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.619 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.652 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager has
>   finished in 33 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.652 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished
>   in 18 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.670 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
>   canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.691 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has
>   finished in 21 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:16.691 INFO
>   [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples canerapp_1  |
>   31-Aug-2016 08:33:17.051 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples has
>   finished in 360 ms canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:17.058 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-apr-8080"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:17.065 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-apr-8009"] canerapp_1  | 31-Aug-2016 08:33:17.066 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 970 ms
>   caner@vegan:~/IdeaProjects/homework$

and i think usr,/localtomcat doesnot exist:

> aner@vegan:/usr$ ls bin  games  include  lib  local  locale  sbin 
>   share  src caner@vegan:/usr$ cd l lib/    local/  locale/ 
>   caner@vegan:/usr$ cd locale caner@vegan:/usr/locale$ ls da
>   caner@vegan:/usr/locale$ cd caner@vegan:~$ cd /usr/local/ bin/
>   etc/     games/   include/ lib/     man/     sbin/    share/   src/
>   caner@vegan:~$ cd /usr/local/ caner@vegan:/usr/local$ ls etc/
>   caner@vegan:/usr/local$ ls lib/ node_modules  python2.7  python3.5

I cant see anythng in localhost.

Comment: You're not adding your html files from your host to your container. Therefore, your Tomcat can't find them and can't serve them. Also you don't need docker-compose, just a plain Dockerfile, if any.

Comment: You can start with an empty Docker image from Docker Hub. To start a Tomcat Server, use this command: `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0`, then navigate to localhost:8888 (see this source: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/)

Comment: But i need to run with docker-compose up so i need it badly. i can run my html with the command similar to yours from here https://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-docker-image-deployment-and-usage but i cant do from compose, i dont need build,  i use image, that cant be reasn?

Comment: A Dockerfile can also use pre-built images https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/from

Comment: "and i think usr,/localtomcat doesnot exist" that's correct, because you are looking on your host. But in your container this path exists. You're mixing host / container paths and you don't know the difference. You should first study some docker basics...

Comment: You can connect to your container and see what's inside it with this command: `docker exec -it homework_canerapp_1 bash`. There you'll find /usr/local/tomcat/webapps as I described it in my answer.

Comment: Yes i just did it and say my index.html  thank you sir really. you taught me lots of things. you did not only postanswer, helped me to understand mapping thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation seem to be pretty broken, please change it to

```
version: '2'
services: 
  canerapp:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html
```

Also as you see, you shall not use the older version:1 syntax but rather the current version:2 syntax with services.

Beside that, i am not sure what the tomcat container requires you to deploy an app. Pretty sure /home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html is the wrong destination, but that should be part of a different question "how to deploy webapps into a tomcat container"

Comment: Those are the wrong ports and the wrong volume mounting.

Comment: Well port mapping was not specifically part of his question, though i corrected it, that you. This question in general is way to broad, there are issues an several layers - i covered the compose part and the general compose syntax here, other questions should be opened for the follow ups

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file should look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/html
```

Then access your project at http://localhost:8888/html.

This maps Tomcats port 8080 to your host port 8888 and then mounts your host volume in `/home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html` to the webapps folder in your container `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/html`.

But using docker-compose is not necessary here, because you don't "compose" multiple containers. You only have one and therefore a Dockerfile is sufficient.

Comment: You're still using Tomcat and want to serve your files with it, don't you? Therefore, `/var/www/html` is not the correct path. This is a possible path for an Apache2 Server

Comment: i agreee, i dont need apache. but i get those errrorsedit: no errrors thank you :D but when i http://localhost:8888/ go to here i can see also. why is it? and thanks. i need to read, you are right.

Comment: How does your docker-compose.yml file look like? Seems you're missing a colon, dash or something like this. My configuration is fine, I tested it on my machine.

Comment: Is your docker-compose up to date? I've got docker-compose version 1.8.0 installed. You should install it with pip `pip install docker-compose` since Ubuntu etc. don't serve an up-to-date version of it in their repositories.

Comment: Now when i go to http://localhost:8888/html i can see, without html only apache page. i think it must be like that.

Comment: What you see depends on the content of your `/home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html` folder. There should be an index.html or something like this for testing.

Comment: Without `/html` you can see the standard index.html provided by Tomcat

Comment: a Dockerfile is never sufficient, i have no clue were people have ever read that. `docker run` is, in 99% in any way worse then `docker-compose up`, even for exactly one service. From build configuration, prefconigured ports, mounts and so on. "EXPOSE" in a Dockerfile does not export any port on the host, so it is not sufficient at all.

Comment: Nope, that is wrong. I am daily working with it. You can do exactly the same things concerning mounting, exposing ports, starting up the service, ... Compose is only interesting when you have multiple services and want to link them.

Comment: Exposing ports with docker run looks like this: `docker run -p 8888:8080 tomcat`

Comment: why negative point? and when i do docker images to see my image name to be able to docker run myimagename (normally it is homework_app_1 but it did not work) , i cant find my image.

Comment: @fff you don't see it, because the container's name is homework_app_1. The image is tomcat, as you defined it in your compose file. You didn't build your own image, just used a pre-built to get your container.

Comment: @EugenMayer the solution without docker-compose looks something like this: `docker run -p 8888:8080 -v /home/caner/IdeaProjects/homework/html:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/html tomcat`. You don't even need a Dockerfile for this task. One-line solution without pip dependencies

Comment: how is that more convenient? How is that sufficient? There is no single advantage in using `docker run` for any day to day task. You can use it for one-shots to start a container to debug an image - solo, but nothing else makes sense. You even have to save this command somewhere or use a shell-script.

Comment: so i cant use docker run to run this compse?

Comment: @EugenMayer depends on what you need. For most of my images / containers I don't need the mounting, so the command is much smaller. One big advantage in not using docker-compose is: you don't need to have python installed and you don't have a pip dependency. Really depends on the use-case. I tried some weeks ago to distribute some containers with docker-compose and all Windows users got stuck at the point where they needed python and pip

Comment: @ff to run a docker-compose.yml file, you actually need docker-compose ;-)